# One RewriteRule for two cases

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need a rewrite rule to load a site that sometimes needs one and someties two variables.

I need to acces my Site by calling:

```
blubb.com/user123
blubb.com/user123/
```

should be rewritten to `/profile.php?username=user123`

and

```
blubb.com/user123/photos
blubb.com/user123/photos/
```

should be rewritten to `/profile.php?username=user123&site=photos`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?username=$1&site=$2 [NC]
```

With the Rule above i get it to work to call `blubb.com/user123/` and `blubb.com/user123/photos` but not the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Tou really should 301 redirect your urls with a trailing slash to the identical URL without the slash (in a separate rewrite). If both of them serve out the same content, Google will see that as content dilution and penalize you for it.

This ought to do it:

```
# Redirect trailing slash to no trailing slash for Google:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

# Route appropriately
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1&site=$2 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks! it works almost perfectly. only problem is that blubb.com/user123/ (with the slash) gives me a error404. The other 3 cases work perfectly

Comment: By the way, you really should 301 redirect your urls with a trailing slash to the identical URL without the slash (in a separate rewrite).  If both of them serve out the same content, Google will see that as content dilution and penalize you for it.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to do that.  Would you mind giving me the checkmark? :)

Comment: i will for sure, but unfortunately it isnt working^^ copied your whole code and my .htacces now looks like that:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

# Redirect trailing slash to no trailing slash for Google:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

# Route appropriately
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/[^/]+)?$ /profile.php?username=$1&site=$2 [NC,QSA]
</IfModule>

Comment: but if i type http://localhost/user123/photos  the "photos" is getting ignored i land on the user123 site

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)(/([0-9A-Za-z]*)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1&site=$3 [NC]
```